# How to get Bitrate from uridecodebin Deepstream source

Tags: python, video-streaming, encoder-decoder, deepstream

For decoding online and local mp4 files, I am using this code snippet to create source bin in Deepstream Python code.(similar to deepstream_test_3 example) This is uridecodebin based source, and handles all decoding part.  I need bitrate info of source video, so as I can set the same to encoder of my output video. Please help me on this.

```
def decodebin_child_added(child_proxy,Object,name,user_data):
    print("Decodebin child added:", name, "\n")
    if(name.find("decodebin") != -1):
        Object.connect("child-added",decodebin_child_added,user_data)

    if "source" in name:
        source_element = child_proxy.get_by_name("source")
        if source_element.find_property('drop-on-latency') != None:
            Object.set_property("drop-on-latency", True)

def cb_newpad(decodebin, decoder_src_pad,data):
    print("In cb_newpad\n")
    caps=decoder_src_pad.get_current_caps()
    if not caps:
        caps = decoder_src_pad.query_caps()

    gststruct=caps.get_structure(0)
    gstname=gststruct.get_name()
    source_bin=data
    features=caps.get_features(0)

    # Need to check if the pad created by the decodebin is for video and not
    # audio.
    print("gstname=",gstname)
    if(gstname.find("video")!=-1):
        # Link the decodebin pad only if decodebin has picked nvidia
        # decoder plugin nvdec_*. We do this by checking if the pad caps contain
        # NVMM memory features.
        print("features=",features)
        if features.contains("memory:NVMM"):
            # Get the source bin ghost pad
            bin_ghost_pad=source_bin.get_static_pad("src")
            if not bin_ghost_pad.set_target(decoder_src_pad):
                sys.stderr.write("Failed to link decoder src pad to source bin ghost pad\n")
        else:
            sys.stderr.write(" Error: Decodebin did not pick nvidia decoder plugin.\n")

def create_source_bin(index,uri):
    print("Creating source bin")

    # Create a source GstBin to abstract this bin's content from the rest of the
    # pipeline
    bin_name="source-bin-%02d" %index
    print(bin_name)
    nbin=Gst.Bin.new(bin_name)
    if not nbin:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create source bin \n")

    # Source element for reading from the uri.
    # We will use decodebin and let it figure out the container format of the
    # stream and the codec and plug the appropriate demux and decode plugins.
    uri_decode_bin=Gst.ElementFactory.make("uridecodebin", "uri-decode-bin")
    if not uri_decode_bin:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create uri decode bin \n")
    # We set the input uri to the source element
    uri_decode_bin.set_property("uri",uri)
    # Connect to the "pad-added" signal of the decodebin which generates a
    # callback once a new pad for raw data has beed created by the decodebin
    uri_decode_bin.connect("pad-added",cb_newpad,nbin)
    uri_decode_bin.connect("child-added",decodebin_child_added,nbin)

    # We need to create a ghost pad for the source bin which will act as a proxy
    # for the video decoder src pad. The ghost pad will not have a target right
    # now. Once the decode bin creates the video decoder and generates the
    # cb_newpad callback, we will set the ghost pad target to the video decoder
    # src pad.
    Gst.Bin.add(nbin,uri_decode_bin)
    bin_pad=nbin.add_pad(Gst.GhostPad.new_no_target("src",Gst.PadDirection.SRC))
    if not bin_pad:
        sys.stderr.write(" Failed to add ghost pad in source bin \n")
        return None
    return nbin

print("Creating source_bin\n")
source_bin=create_source_bin(0, "<video_path_uri>")
if not source_bin:
    sys.stderr.write("Unable to create source bin \n")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found direct method with deepstream, but we can get bitrate by other mean. I works for both URL and local file. This function solved my issue:

```
import subprocess

def get_video_bitrate(filename):
    result = subprocess.Popen(
        ["ffprobe", "-v", "error", "-select_streams", "v:0", "-show_entries",
         "stream=bit_rate", "-of", "default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1", filename],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
    )
    output = result.communicate()[0]
    bitrate = int(output.strip())
    return bitrate
```